# Do C++ developers commonly count on implicit casting?

Tags: c++, standards

I've been given the task of porting a Windows program to OS X. Originally written in C++, I'm enjoying it because I don't often work with the C family of languages, and have enjoyed making use of Objective C++ in the port.

However, the Windows source code does something strange, and I'm wondering if it's a standard practice. The API we're working with on both Windows and OS X expects a particular object method to be passed an unsigned short. The original Windows developer created the following function to calculate this value:

```
static unsigned short hashcode ( const char* value ) {
  int h = 0 ;
  unsigned long length = strlen ( value ) ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ) {
    h = ( 31 * h ) + value[i] ;
  }    

  return h ;
}
```

Note that while the function returns an `unsigned short`, the variable it's returning is declared as an `int`. I've checked the documentation, and both OS X and Windows define an `unsigned short` as 2 bytes and an `int` as 4.

The value being passed to this function, if the data type isn't taken into account, results in the function returning very large numbers, dozens of digits in some cases. In one case, where I duplicated the algorithm in another language with less strict types, I got a value of `2081357292912430390912`. When I wraped the above function in a command line utility, the same string returned a value of `40576`, I'm guessing because that's the truncated version of the longer value.

So I have two questions. First of all, why, if `hashcode` is declared to return an `unsigned short` and it's in fact returning and `int` doesn't the compiler complain? Isn't that what strict data type declarations are for in the first place? To make sure that functions and methods receive and return the data types expected?

And second, is this truncation a standard practice? It seems very strange to me, first of all to take advantage of the implicit casting, but also there's no commenting to call out to someone that that's what's happening (and I don't have access to the original developer to ask). Since it isn't commented as being something "special," perhaps it's simply a standard idiom in C/C++?

Comment: What is "automatic casting"? That's an oxymoron? Either you cast, or you don't.

Comment: Perhaps "implicit casting" is a better term? `return h` vs. `return (unsigned short) h`?

Comment: I think you mean "implicit conversion" instead of "automatic cast". In C++, casts are explicit conversions.

Comment: I don't think that the C++ compiler won't complain about the function returning a variable of a different type

Comment: Please submit this source code for a so-called "hash code" to http://www.thedailywtf.com

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, is it really *that* bad? I'm not a full-time C developer, so I thought perhaps it's just normal for C/C++/Objective C/Objective C++. :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, why? This is a djb hash function, not a too bad one.

Comment: @ForceBru perhaps he is referencing the h = 0 (instead of h = 1)

Comment: @aepryus What makes `1` a better initial value for `h`?

Comment: @aepryus, err, `h` should actually be zero, not one.

Comment: That's actually a cleaned up version of the original function, BTW. The original actually placed the `for` loop in an `if ( h == 0 )` block and had an `offset` variable that was always the same value as `i`, but incremented separately, i.e., `h = ( 31 * h ) + value[offset++]`.

Comment: With regard to the implicit cast loosing information, increase the warning level of the compiler you are using.

Comment: @ForceBru I was just speculating; I have seen it implemented with h initialized with 1, but I have no metric to evaluate the relative merit of either.  But, I would be curious if there was a reason that 0 was better than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, why, if hashcode is declared to return an unsigned short and it's in fact returning and int doesn't the compiler complain?

Because the conversion from `int` to `unsigned short` can be performed implicitly

> Isn't that what strict data type declarations are for in the first place? To make sure that functions and methods receive and return the data types expected?

Yes. And that's exactly what's happening here. The function declared as returning `unsigned short` *is* returning `unsigned short`, as a result of that implicit conversion.

> And second, is this truncation a standard practice?

Yes.

A good reason why it's not made explicit in the code with a cast is that C++ has a set of conversions that can be performed implicitly, and a larger set of conversions that can be performed explicitly. The latter set includes some potentially dangerous conversions, such as those between pointers and integers. Taking advantage of implicit conversions except where explicit casts are required protects against accidentally performing one of the dangerous conversions.

<sub>I do see a potential problem with this implementation, but it's not relevant to your question. I think it's better not to go into detail, just don't misinterpret my answer as endorsement of this function.</sub>

Comment: I guess I assumed that any supported implicit conversion would be relegated to those that can't lose data, such as `int` to `short`, while conversions that *could* lose data would have to be explicit to work without compiler warnings. And, of course, your footnote has raised my curiosity, so please, what potential problem do you see?

Comment: @Chuck Using the wrong type for storing `strlen`'s result, calling `strlen` at all when there is no need for it, but the big thing is that the multiplication will cause integer overflow for anything but the shortest strings, which unlike the implicit conversions isn't required to do anything sensible.

Comment: Well, that function won't exist in the port. :)

Comment: For avoiding the dangerous conversions, there's always `boost::implicit_cast<T>` (or roll-your-own)

Comment: I dunno: change every type innside the function to `unsigned int` or even `unsigned short` and it stops doing stupid undefined behaviour.  Given truncation, there is zero point in `h` being bigger than unsigned short afaict: but add some shuffles to the hash accumulation `h=h<<6+h>>2+value[i];` to shuffle more bits.  Or steal boost hash combine.

Comment: @hvd oh ya, those suck.  Not certain if the unsigned short could result in strange overflow?  Doubt it: still, just unsigned int everywhere and prevent any kind of integer promotion?

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and assume you mean implicit conversion rather than automatic casting. From my experience, this behavior is commonly relied on in many languages, including C++. To answer your first question, this will not cause a compiler error as long as a conversion sequence exists between the type being assigned from and the type being assigned to.

Often in conditionals people will pass in integers without explicitly writing `== 0` or `!= 0`.

Examples:

```
int count = 10;
while (--count); // runs 10 times

int test = 0;
if (test); // evaluates to false

test = 1;
if (test); // evaluates to true

test = -1;
if (test); // evaluates to true
```

Here's some documentation on implicit conversions http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: I've seen integer and pointer types used as boolean tests many times. I guess I kind of placed this in a different category.

Comment: Yeah it has a different _feel_ to it, but is the same mechanism